# How to call a method of a class without instantiating it?

Tags: typescript, import, export

I created a Tools class to extends every class from it as it contains set of functions that all class uses.

I export my class like so:

Tools.ts

```
export abstract class Tools {
  getRandom(bytes) {
    return 21 // Example
  }
}
```

Main.ts

```
import * as Tools from './Tools.ts'

class Main extends Tools { // <-- I get the error from the Tools keyword here
  constructor() {
    super() // If not, I get an error
  }

  token() { // Example method
    this.getRandom(2)
  }
}
```

The error I get:

```
Type 'typeof import("[...]/tools")' is not a constructor function type
```

I don't want to use `new Tools()` in every class, I'd like to call the function of the class directly.

How can I achieve importing a class and calling it's methods without instantiating the class in every other one ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although your problem was solved previously I want to chime in since I think you want to achieve something that is semantically different from extending a class. Storing utility functions in a `Tools` class and extending it will prevent you from further inheritance. Furthermore you might want to use only a single utility function but still inherit ALL of them, which would be horrible in the case of lodash.

What you are most likely looking for, are so-called static methods. Class methods that can be called directly without a particular instance of the class.

```
// In Tools.ts
export class Tools {
    // https://xkcd.com/221/
    public static getRandomNumber() {
        return 4; // chosen by fair dice roll.
                  // guaranteed to be random. 
    }
}

// Somewhere else
import { Tools } from "./Tools";

export class Main {
    public doSomething() {
        const randomNumber = Tools.getRandomNumber();
    }
}
```

However, in TypeScript it is usually discouraged to export classes that only consist of static methods and those methods should be encapsulated in their very own functions that you can import explicitly in order to reduce bundle size:

```
// In Tools.ts
export function getRandomNumber() {
    // https://xkcd.com/221/
    return 4; // chosen by fair dice roll.
              // guaranteed to be random. 
}

// Somewhere else
import { getRandomNumber } from "./Tools";

export class Main {
    public doSomething() {
        const randomNumber = getRandomNumber();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh damn son! Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for in fact. Also, you may find this one funny too: https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25 (it is my inspiration) you made my day.

Comment: usage of static and also to tell the recommended way to use export functions deserves 

Answer (score 1):

You're using a *named export*, so your import statement should look like this:

```
import { Tools } from './Tools.ts'
```

If you don't like calling `super` explicitly, you can skip the `constructor`. In that case, JavaScript runtime will call it for you.

```
class Main extends Tools {
  token() {
    this.getRandom(2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you for your help! I didn't think of that!